# Firebase plugin depends on guava jdk-5 conflict

Tags: android, firebase

I'm getting compile error at line 1 of app.gradle

> Firebase plugin depends on guava jdk-5

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    // FireBase Crash Reporting
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
```

*app.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash' // FireBase Crash Reporting plugin to uplaod the mapping file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update firebase plugin and that should fix the problem:

```
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
```

Or exclude guava-jdk5 from the plugin.

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```